# How to set stage name across all CDK resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a requirement to append stage name to the name of the resources created by CDK for eg

```
bucket-dev
```

To tackle this I pick context value using cmd `cdk bootstrap -c config=dev`, extract this main.ts file

```
const env = app.node.tryGetContext('config')
// pass it as pipelineEnv
```

Then I pass on to stacks as props.
But my issue is that for every resource name now I have to specify env `(props.pipelineEnv)` and I think this leads to redundant code for example

```
   Bucket1Name: getResourceName(this, `bucket-${props.AccountId}`, 'artifact', props.pipelineEnv),
      Bucket2Name: getResourceName(this, `bucket-${props.AccountId}`, 'state', props.pipelineEnv)
```

Is there a way to set it across all cdk resources, like define it only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "global prefix" in CDK. The oficial way to customize logical names is to override the class resource.

There's a TypeScript example on the CDK samples repository:

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/typescript/custom-logical-names

It requires a base stack building the prefix:

```js
export class BaseStack extends Stack {
  public allocateLogicalId(element: CfnElement) {
    const orig = super.allocateLogicalId(element);
    const prefix = this.node.tryGetContext('prefix');
    return prefix ? prefix + orig : orig;
  }
}
```

And you need to extend from it in all your resources:

```js
class MyStack extends BaseStack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new sns.Topic(this, 'MyTopic');
    new s3.Bucket(this, 'MyBucket');
  }
}
```

### Example

```bash
$ cdk synth -j
{
  "Resources": {
    "MyTopic86869434": {
      "Type": "AWS::SNS::Topic"
    },
    "MyBucketF68F3FF0": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    }
  }
}
```

Now with prefix:

```bash
$ cdk synth -j -c prefix="MyTeam"
{
  "Resources": {
    "MyTeamMyTopic86869434": {
      "Type": "AWS::SNS::Topic"
    },
    "MyTeamMyBucketF68F3FF0": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    }
  }
}
```

CDK RFC is still open:

- https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk-rfcs/issues/83#issuecomment-531207448